# scala slick - complex function in select clause

Tags: scala, sum, aggregate, slick, notnull

I have a join table that holds the id of 'a', 'b' and a couple of Option[Long] related to the a<->b relation. I'd like to query it like this:

```
select a_id, sum(longField is not null) from a_b_info group by a_id
```

(ignoring b_id in this query...)

I tried all kinds of stuff but was unable to achieve this.
How can I do it with slick?

Comment: Are you sure this is even valid SQL?

Comment: I forgot the from clause, but except for that it's valid, works and tested. added the from clause...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create your own function. Slick is very extensible, but it's a deep dive to add a function. As an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14920153/how-to-write-nested-queries-in-select-clause/14989939#14989939) I extended the driver to add the `as` function. You would need to take similar steps to achieve the same for your problem.

Comment: Alternatively, couldn't you just map over the column and have the same effect? Or, is this what your `as` function does?

Comment: I am not sure if that has the same effect. The example with the `as` function shows how you can generate arbitrary SQL that is not supported by Slick directly.

Comment: I was hoping for an answer that would would involve creating my own function (with SimpleExpression perhaps?). I tried to do this myself but sadly was unable to solve my prob. Also it didn't help that the  documentation about custom functions is very basic...
I didn't try your solution yet but i'm pretty sure it would work. I'd just need to add a "asSum" keyword that would wrap the former experssion with sum(expr). I will try it after i give the custom function way some more.

Comment: Yeah, I made it a `FunctionSymbol`, you could switch that out for something else. Whatever fits best.