# "Select In" using Slick

Tags: scala, slick

Is there a way to perform a query like this in Slick:

```
"select * from foo where id IN (select other_id from bar where status = 'damaged')"
```

Thanks

Comment: This is a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14920153/how-to-write-nested-queries-in-select-clause

Answer (score 4):

```
for{
    f <- foo,
    b <- bar if (b.status === 'damaged' && f.id === b.other_id)
} yield f
```

this produces

```
select x2."id" from "foo" x2, "bar" x3 
    where (x2."id" = x3."other_id") and (x3."status" = 'damaged')
```

which is equivalent in terms of rows returned. If you need that exact query for some reason you'll probably need to either extend slick or use a static query.

Answer (score 1):

yes:

the imports:

`import scala.slick.jdbc.{ GetResult, StaticQuery => Q }`

`import Q.interpolation`

the result, and the conversion to the result:

`case class FooResult(id: Int, name: String)`

`implicit val getPersonResult = GetResult(r => FooResult(r.<<, r.<<))`

your query:

`val status = "damaged"`

`val q = Q.query[String,FooResult]("select * from foo where id IN (select other_id from bar where status = ?)")`

`val result = q.list(status)`