# How to write nested queries in select clause with slick 3.2 +

Tags: scala, slick

Is there any way to create nested select using slick 3.2+ ?
Basically all that I need described here [How to write nested queries in select clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14920153/how-to-write-nested-queries-in-select-clause)

However on slick 3.2 this approach does not work.

Answer (score 1):

If you have tables `Users` (id: UUID, email: String) and `Persons` (userId: UUID, name: String, surname: String) than query

```
select email
from Users
where id in (select userId
             from Persons
             where name = 'John'
             and surname = 'Smith')
```

would look kind of like:

```
users
  .filter(
    _.id in persons
              .filter(p => p.name === "John" && p.surname === "Smith")
              .map(_.userId)
  )
  .map(_.email)
  .result
```

Things you need to remember:

- `Query` type is not `DBIO` (nor `DBIOAction`) - if you want to compose queries, you need to do it before calling `.result` on them
- when you are using subquery in condition use `in` instead of `inSet`

Same principle should hold whether you use `in`, `join`, etc.

Comment: Thanks but I need nested select  ie. select p.1, (select a.2 from tableA a where p.id = a.id ) from tableA as p

Comment: You can rewrite it: `( tableA.map(a => (a.id, a.2)) join tableB.map(b.id, b.1) on (_._1 === _._1) ).map(_._4)`. Alternatively, just use `sql"""query"""`.